# How to prevent listview from jumping to selected/focused row on item.count change?

Tags: listview, delphi, vcl, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a virtual listview, which I'm planning on using to display things from a rather large log file.

Any time a line is added or removed and I have a row selected or focused (or both) in the listbox, it will automatically scroll back to it, which is very annoying.

Feels like something makes a call for the MakeVisible (or something that does the same thing) when the item count is modified.

Very simplified example to reproduce it:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Col: TListColumn;
begin
  ListView1.OwnerData := True;
  ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport;
  ListView1.RowSelect := True;

  Col := ListView1.Columns.Add;
  Col.Caption := 'LineNum';
  Col.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
  Col.Width := 70;
end;
// listview onData event
procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := IntToStr(Item.Index+1);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.Items.Count := ListView1.Items.Count + 10;
end;
```

Edit: Testing different ViewStyles, this only happens with vsReport and vsList

Comment: Which Delphi version? VCL or FMX?

Comment: Probably VCL as the uses list consists of VCL.whatevers, its the 10.2 tokyo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  problem is that the `TListItems.Count` property setter calls [`ListView_SetItemCountEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_setitemcountex) without the `LVSICF_NOSCROLL` flag:

> The list-view control will not change the scroll position when the item count changes.

```
procedure TListItems.SetCount(Value: Integer);
begin
  if Value <> 0 then
    ListView_SetItemCountEx(Handle, Value, LVSICF_NOINVALIDATEALL)
  else
    ListView_SetItemCountEx(Handle, Value, 0);
end;
```

That is why the ListView scrolls whenever the `Count` changes. You will have to call `ListView_SetItemCountEx()` yourself directly so that you can specify the `LVSICF_NOSCROLL` flag.

```
uses
  ..., CommCtrl;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //ListView1.Items.Count := ListView1.Items.Count + 10;
  ListView_SetItemCountEx(ListView1.Handle, ListView1.Items.Count + 10, LVSICF_NOINVALIDATEALL or LVSICF_NOSCROLL);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this completely solved the problem, I was actually already looking into the header files, but didn't get to looking up the flags.